# Initial paint of QStyledItemDelegate has the wrong height

Tags: python, pyside2, qstyleditemdelegate

I am attempting to use a `QStyledItemDelegate` with my `QListView` to display rich text in the items.

The first time the item is painted its height is too small. If I then mouse over the item it gets repainted with the correct height. Below are screenshots of the initial paint and repaint.

How can I get the initial paint to be the right height?

[image: Initial height is too small.]
[image: After first repaint the height is just right.]

Example code that demonstrates the issue:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class RichTextItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RichTextItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()

        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        self.doc.setHtml(option.text)

        option_no_text = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        option_no_text.text = ''
        style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style() if option_no_text.widget is None else option_no_text.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option_no_text, painter)

        margin_top = (option.rect.height() - self.doc.size().height()) // 2
        text_rect = style.subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, option_no_text, None)
        text_rect.setTop(text_rect.top() + margin_top)

        painter.translate(text_rect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(text_rect.translated(-text_rect.topLeft()))

        context = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, context)

        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        other = super().sizeHint(option, index)
        w = min(self.doc.idealWidth(), other.width())
        h = max(self.doc.size().height(), other.height())
        return QtCore.QSize(w, h)


class ExampleWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item.setText('Example<br><span style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;">Example<br>Example<br>Example</span>', )

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.appendRow(item)

        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView(parent=self)
        self.listview.setModel(model)

        delegate = RichTextItemDelegate(self.listview)
        self.listview.setItemDelegate(delegate)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
example = ExampleWidget()
example.resize(320, 240)
example.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I do not reproduce your problem, you could indicate the characteristics of your environment: python version, pyside2 version, OS, etc.

Comment: Windows 10, Python 3.7.6, PySide2 5.15.0.

Comment: I see `sizeHint()` get called 5 times before `paint()` gets called... I just don't know what to do about that.

Comment: mmm, it seems to be a bug, what do you get by adding `print(w, h)`? Try setting the delegate before setting the model

Comment: Moving `setItemDelegate` has no effect. I see a call sequence like: `sizeHint: 8.0, 24.0; paint; sizeHint: 107.0, 108.0;`. Since `self.doc.setHtml` doesn't get called until `paint` I think that is what I would expect. I wonder how I can set the doc text before paint is called.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the initial paint was sized wrong because the `sizeHint()` function can't return good values until it knows what the item text is. In my original code the text wasn't set until `paint()` was called.

I used the following for `sizeHint()` and it seems to work:

```
def sizeHint(self, option: QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.QSize:
    self.doc.setHtml(index.data())
    doc_size = self.doc.size()
    doc_width = int(math.ceil(doc_size.width()))
    doc_height = int(math.ceil(doc_size.height()))

    item_size = super().sizeHint(option, index)

    w = min(doc_width, item_size.width())
    h = max(doc_height, item_size.height())

    return QtCore.QSize(w, h)
```

Be warned... I do not know what the implications of calling `self.doc.setHtml()` inside of `sizeHint()` are. Also, for some reason `super().sizeHint()` returns a very large width value for me, and I'm not sure why, which is why I call `min()` instead of `max()`.